# No tables used?

Tags: mysql, sql, wamp

I've been working with this bit of code for some time now, and now, after some tinkering, I thought I finally got it to work, then it gives me this error:

> Error Number: 1096
>       No tables used
>       SELECT *

and this is the code

```
SELECT start.*, posts.did, COUNT(posts.pid)
                            FROM akia_starting_posts AS start
                            JOIN posts
                                ON posts.did = start.did
                            JOIN akia_users AS users
                                ON users.username = start.username
```

I'm pretty sure at the `*` my `start` is being used, so what  is it talking about?  It couldn't be any other code in the file, since when I take out this bit of code, it starts working.

Comment: Are you using Sql Server?

Comment: Please provide some context: What did you do? Did you execute the SQL you give? On what DBMS? What is the schema? How did you execute the SQL (which tool)?

Comment: @Steve I honestly don't know, I'm working on localhost with WAMP, if I think i know what you're referring to then I think I'm on MySQL (Sorry, bit of a newbie)

Comment: I will try to change that table name, use something less ambiguous. I don't know for MySql, but for example in Sql Server that word (START) is listed between the future reserved keywords used by the internal Language T-SQL

Comment: Well I used the `start` before, but I just added a join with the `posts.did` and `COUNT` and now it's messing up.

Comment: But, PROBABLY before you have it after the FROM not after the SELECT. Ok just a try

Answer (score 0):

Try to add backticks on sql string that has the word start on it. To begin try to use the one table in question first like.

```
SELECT 'start.*' FROM akia_starting_posts as 'start'
```

and if it works then you may incorporate it in fullscale join like the one you posted
with bacticks used.